# Spring Security - when upgrading from 5.7.5 to 5.84., it still uses 5.7.9 HttpSecurity - is that normal?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to upgrade Spring Security from 5.7.5 to 5.8.4 to prep for spring security 6.

This is what i have for relevant dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

> ```
>     @Configuration
>     @EnableWebSecurity
>     public class aSecurityConfig {
>
>     @Bean
>     public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
> ....}
> ```

I am using the above type of format but when I go inside EnableWebSecurity annoncation and HttpSecurity, they are 5.7.9 files. Is that normal?

Using 2.7.13 spring boot version

Comment: can you add a screenshot of where is this 5.7.9 files

Answer (score 0):

i got all of them to point to 5.8.4 now by adding version

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Before the app was failing and i think it is now working because i added the spring-security-config dependency which i did not have and had not tried putting a specific version.